# How to get the default value for the Transaction Period and Financial Period in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I have a customization form that I need to fill “Transaction Period” and company’s “Financial Period” by defult from a date field and the selected branch but I can not make it work. I reviewed a couple Acumatica’s owen screens and I’m doing exctly the same (at least I think so) but these two fields are not filled by default. Any help appreciated. Here is my little Graph, partial DAC and Partial ASPX.

```
namespace MyCustom

}

// Graph

public class PMCashflowProjectionEntry : PXGraph<PMCashflowProjectionEntry, PMCashflowProjection>

{



    [PXViewName("Projects Cashflow Projections")]

    public PXSelect<PMCashflowProjection> CashflowProjections;



    public PXSelect<PMCashflowProjectionSchedule, Where<PMCashflowProjectionSchedule.projectID, Equal<Current<PMCashflowProjection.projectID>>>> CashflowProjectionSchedules;



}



//Partial Header DAC

public class PMCashflowProjection : IBqlTable

{

    #region BranchID

    public abstract class branchID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<branchID> { }

    protected Int32? _BranchID;

    [Branch()]

    [PXForeignReference(typeof(Field<branchID>.IsRelatedTo<Branch.branchID>))]

    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Branch", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, Required = true, Enabled = true, Visible = true)]

    public virtual Int32? BranchID

    {

        get

        {

            return this._BranchID;

        }

        set

        {

            this._BranchID = value;

        }

    }

    #endregion



}



//Partial Detail DAC

public class PMCashflowProjectionSchedule : IBqlTable

{

    #region Date

    public abstract class date : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDateTime.Field<date> { }

    protected DateTime? _Date;

    [PXDBDate()]

    [PXDefault(typeof(AccessInfo.businessDate), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]

    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Date", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, Required = true, Enabled = true, Visible = true, IsReadOnly = false)]

    public virtual DateTime? Date

    {

        get

        {

            return this._Date;

        }

        set

        {

            this._Date = value;

        }

    }

    #endregion



    #region TranPeriodID

    public abstract class tranPeriodID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<tranPeriodID> { }

    protected String _TranPeriodID;

    [PXDefault()]

    [PeriodID(

        searchType: null,

        sourceType: typeof(date),

        defaultType: null,

        redefaultOnDateChanged: true)]

    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Tran. Period", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, Required = true, Enabled = true, Visible = true)]

    public virtual String TranPeriodID

    {

        get

        {

            return this._TranPeriodID;

        }

        set

        {

            this._TranPeriodID = value;

        }

    }

    #endregion



    #region FinPeriodID

    public abstract class finPeriodID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<finPeriodID> { }

    protected String _FinPeriodID;

    [PXDefault()]

    [FinPeriodID(

        sourceType: typeof(date),

        branchSourceType: typeof(PMCashflowProjection.branchID),

        masterFinPeriodIDType: typeof(tranPeriodID),

        headerMasterFinPeriodIDType: typeof(tranPeriodID),

        redefaultOnDateChanged: true)]

    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Fin. Period", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, Required = true, Enabled = true, Visible = true)]

    public virtual String FinPeriodID

    {

        get

        {

            return this._FinPeriodID;

        }

        set

        {

            this._FinPeriodID = value;

        }

    }

    #endregion

}

}
```

Partial ASPX Example

```
//Form




        <px:PXSegmentMask runat="server" ID="edBranchID" DataField="BranchID" CommitChanges="True" AutoRefresh="True" />




//Grid Clumns

        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Date" Width="80" CommitChanges="True" ></px:PXGridColumn>

        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="TranPeriodID" Width="80" CommitChanges="True" ></px:PXGridColumn>

        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="FinPeriodID" Width="80" CommitChanges="True" ></px:PXGridColumn>



// Grid Row Template

        <px:PXDateTimeEdit runat="server" ID="edDate" DataField="Date" CommitChanges="True" AutoRefresh="True" ></px:PXDateTimeEdit>

        <px:PXMaskEdit runat="server" ID="edTranPeriodID" DataField="TranPeriodID" CommitChanges="True" Size="s" ></px:PXMaskEdit>

        <px:PXMaskEdit runat="server" ID="edFinPeriodID" DataField="FinPeriodID" CommitChanges="True" Size="s" ></px:PXMaskEdit>
```

Answer (score 0):

The work of PeriodId attribute and its descendants looks kind of tricky, as they share their cache. Without doing this customization and debugging, the rule of a thumb is to mimic the declaration of multiple out-of-the box DACs using these periods. I see two differencies of this declaration from standard which might play a role:

1. FinPeriodId generally precedes the TranPeriodId declaration. It looks important because the source field  used for the periodid defaulting comes from the specification for the attribute on the FinPeriodId field
2. In the sourceType declaration, the DAC name is generally specified. So consider using the following syntax:

   [FinPeriodID(
   sourceType: typeof(PMCashflowProjectionSchedule.date),

Answer (score 0):

You could use PXDefault attribute to set a default value on page load and if you would like to allow the users to change the default value the field can be made as a Selector type with PXSelector attribute.

an example below for PXDefault attribute getting default value from the financial periods and current business date :

```
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Fin. Period", Required = true)] 
[FinPeriodIDFormatting()]
[PXDefault(typeof(SearchFor<MasterFinPeriod.finPeriodID>
    .Where<MasterFinPeriod.endDate.IsGreaterEqual<AccessInfo.businessDate.FromCurrent>
    .And<MasterFinPeriod.startDate.IsLessEqual<AccessInfo.businessDate.FromCurrent>>>),
    PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]

[PXSelector(typeof(SearchFor<MasterFinPeriod.finPeriodID>.In<SelectFrom<MasterFinPeriod>
    .Where<MasterFinPeriod.endDate.IsLessEqual<AccessInfo.businessDate.FromCurrent>
    .And<MasterFinPeriod.finPeriodID.IsNotNull>>>
    .OrderBy<MasterFinPeriod.finPeriodID.Desc>>))]
```

FinPeriodIDFormatting() attribute formats to MM-YYYY

```
<px:PXSelector CommitChanges="True" runat="server" ID="edTranPeriodID" DataField="TranPeriodID" ></px:PXSelector>
<px:PXSelector CommitChanges="True" runat="server" ID="edFinPeriodID" DataField="FinPeriodID" ></px:PXSelector>
```